# Why doesn't chmod work on a file under /media?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I want to execute a script file from terminal but it shows error

```
root@silambarasan-PC:/media/D-DEVELOPME/androidSdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/tools# ./android
-bash: ./android: Permission denied`
```

so I saw the file permissions from terminal & tried to give execute permission. but no use even I give permission it won't change.

```
root@silambarasan-PC:/media/D-DEVELOPME/androidSdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/tools# ll android 
-rw-r--r-- 1 silambarasan silambarasan 3498 Dec  6 08:14 android
root@silambarasan-PC:/media/D-DEVELOPME/androidSdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/tools# chmod 777 android 
root@silambarasan-PC:/media/D-DEVELOPME/androidSdk/adt-bundle-linux-x86/sdk/tools# ll android 
-rw-r--r-- 1 silambarasan silambarasan 3498 Dec  6 08:14 android`
```

I don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Easiest would be to copy the executable to your home folder and start it from there.**

But…

It seems your executable is mounted on an external partition. Make sure the partition is not mounted with `noexec`. Try:

```
grep '/media/D-DEVELOPME' /etc/mtab | grep noexec
```

If you see a line containing the word "noexec", try re-mounting the partition without the `noexec` flag:

```
mount -o remount,exec /media/D-DEVELOPME
```

Also make sure your media actually allows you to change the permissions, e.g. you cannot do that on a mounted CD or an SD crad with the read-only switch on.

Comment: I tried Easiest way, works now. Thanks lot @Attila O

Comment: It could also be the `showexec` FAT option which allow the execute permission bit only for .EXE, .COM and .BAT extensions.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `chmod 777 file`, you may use `chmod u+x file`. Where `u` means user and `x` means execution permissons. See `man chmod` pages for more information. I know that 777 gives all permisson for read, write execute for user, group and others, try using the syntax with u+x.