# Chmod wouldn't work, although I can modify files

Tags: mount, permissions

> [Why doesn't chmod work on a file under /media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256794/why-doesnt-chmod-work-on-a-file-under-media)

I am having similar problem. The aim is booting from a clean Ubuntu flash memory stick, then cloning and test-building a large repository onto a hard drive partition.

Unfortunately, my situation is under the restrictions that I can't copy the script, nor does the partition seem to be readonly of noexec.

Here is how the partition is mounted:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad$ grep '/media/ubuntu/data' /etc/mtab | grep noexec
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad$ grep '/media/ubuntu/data' /etc/mtab
/dev/sda4 /media/ubuntu/data fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Here is a demonstration of the problem:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad/build/workspaces$ ll update-workspaces.sh 
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4608 Apr 16 06:41 update-workspaces.sh
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad/build/workspaces$ chmod +x update-workspaces.sh 
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad/build/workspaces$ ll update-workspaces.sh
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 4608 Apr 16 06:41 update-workspaces.sh
```

I researched the mentioned mount options, but forund nothing suspecious.

---

Clarifications:

*1. I can't move the script*, because it is special in that it is a part of a larger build system, that I do not understand. I am following the [build instructions](http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/BuildInstructions) for the application.

*2. The problem is not with what the script contains*, because I tried creating a simple script in the same folder, and that too can't be executed:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Hello World!"`
```

*3. `sudo` doesn't help.*

*4. Here is the full `/etc/mtab`*, as requested. The partition I am trying to use is the last one `data`.

```
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sdb1 on /cdrom type vfat (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/999/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=ubuntu)
/dev/sda6 on /media/ubuntu/2f54e44f-46ee-4e9d-a9b7-05963a5a6b61 type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda1 on /media/ubuntu/571CDF3F0AB7ABFD type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/ubuntu/0b4a4dc5-cf55-429d-85a5-ccb40c3796fc type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sda4 on /media/ubuntu/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

*5. Underlying file system:*

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/data/test/0ad/build/workspaces$ sudo file -sL /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4: x86 boot sector
```

According to GParted, this is a primary ntfs partition. I have a Windown 7 on another partition and an Ubuntu on another set of partitions:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo`? The permissions/account might be a little strange on "live" Ubuntu.

Comment: What's the underlying filesystem of the /dev/sda4 block device (e.g. `sudo file -sL /dev/sda4`)?

Comment: I recommend also including the output of `mount`. ...Also, does the script actually have to be run as an executable, or would it be acceptable to pass its name to the interpreter (e.g., `sh update-workspaces.sh`, assuming it really is intended to be run by `sh`). If you know that won't work, I suggest expanding your question to explain why--otherwise, I suggest posting the first few lines of the script (or at least the first line) so someone can answer with specific details about what interpreter to invoke for it.

Comment: @steeldriver, please see point five from my edited question.